# Can you identify my Haro BMX?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx, chrome

I’m trying to identify my Haro. I think it’s a 1997 Zi Fusion but I’m not sure. The serial number is ZIK6F3265. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A better photo would help, but it does look a lot like https://www.bmx-catalogue.com/haro/mid-school/1997/group-1-zi.html

Check out the rear trackends for similarities, as well as the chainring and head tube markings.  You can also compare the component list with what you have, though remember parts can change over ~25 years.

[image]

---

Clearly both bikes have the same "downward" bend in the top tube, which looks similar.

The link to BMX-Catalogue suggests the bike was available in Silver, yellow, or blue.  I'm not sure if silver means Chrome like yours, or if yours is a different year.

Clearly the chainring is different, yours having holes and the sample having slots.  Also, your rear brake looks like it has been swapped for V brakes, whereas it would have had cantilever brake arms when new.

Comment: I hope that new picture helps.

Comment: Great find. @Haroislife there were many Haro models like yours made over several years. If you go to the BMX Museum and play with the filters you can browse the variety. Here's a link filtered to all [Haro bikes](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/haro/)